# Is there any way to add AppStore review programmatically (by app)?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, app-store, rating

I want to write a review like a usual text and then send it to AppStore from within my app.
I would like to have a copy of this review sent to my e-mail.
And since reviews are premoderated by Apple I would know about the review before it would be posted at AppStore.

Anyway to do this in iOS?

Comment: You cannot rate an app programmatically, from outside the app store. If it were possible, lots of developers would take advantage of it and would rate their apps with 5 stars without the users noticing which would defeat the purpose of a rating system. Even if a password dialog would pop up, a lot of users would not understand why it pops up and simply enter their passwords.

Comment: Well, it's certainly *possible* but also a good way to get kicked out of Apple's developer program...

Comment: Why they didn't provide some way/framework to do this? Apple could authenticate unique user/installation and so prevent the false auto reviews... They could create something like the way they did with SMS sending system.

Comment: Maybe submit a feature request to [bugreport.apple.com](http://bugreport.apple.com).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No this is not possible as this would allow you to create false reviews.